# Avoiding explicit for-loop in Python with pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rank

I would like to find a better way to carry out the following process.

```
#import packages
import pandas as pd
```

I have defined a pandas dataframe.

```
# Create dataframe
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Jason', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Tina'],
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'coverage': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

After the dataframe is created, I want to add an extra column to the dataframe. This column contains the rank based on the values in the coverage column for every name seperately.

```
#Add column with ranks based on 'coverage' for every name separately. 
df_end = pd.DataFrame()
for person_names in df.groupby('name').groups:
    one_name = df.groupby('name').get_group(person_names)
    one_name['coverageRank'] = one_name['coverage'].rank()
    df_end = df_end.append(one_name)
```

Is it possible to achieve this simple task in a simpler way? Maybe without using the for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['coverageRank'] = df.groupby('name')['coverage'].rank()
print (df)
   coverage   name  reports  coverageRank
0        25  Jason        4           1.0
1        94  Jason       24           2.0
2        57   Tina       31           1.0
3        62   Tina        2           2.0
4        70   Tina        3           3.0
```